# What are some advanced methods for bond risk transformations?

Tags: fixed-income, bond, risk

Consider a portfolio of bonds within a given yield curve (e.g. Gilt curve), consisting of positions in every bond in the curve. I'm looking for ways to **transform the risk of the portfolio into estimated representations of the macro/on-the-run buckets**.

For example, the Gilt curve (roughly 55 bonds) has a liquid 5y bond, a liquid 10y bond, and a liquid 30y bond, and the net position of the portfolio may be such that it trades similarly to some combination of the 5y, 10y, and 30y bonds.

The challenge is how to transform the risk representation of 55 bonds (a 1-dimensional vector with 55 elements) into a risk representation of $(5y,10y,30y)$. A few well known methods are outlined below:

**Method 1: PCA**

PCA (Principal Components Analysis) is a well-known method for transforming the risk of a bond portfolio into its macro components. For a bond curve with $n$ bonds, the portfolio risk is $S_A\in\Re^{n\times 1}$. After applying PCA with 3 components, we get a PCA matrix of $P\in\Re^{n\times 3}$. We can roughly represent the macro risk of our portfolio by doing $$S_B=P^TS_A, S_B\in\Re^{3\times 1}$$ This isn't quite what I'm after, but it will give us the outright risk (i.e. the risk of the portfolio to parallel shifts in the curve), curve risk (e.g. roughly the 5s10s position of the portfolio), and butterfly risk (e.g. roughly the 5s10s30s position of the portfolio.

**Method 2: Jacobian Transformation**

Consider our risk vector $S_A$. Now consider that we want to break our risk down into the 3 most liquid points (the 5y, 10y, and 30y points). We generate a jacobian matrix $J\in\Re^{3\times n}$, where $J_{ij}$ ($i\in[1,3]$ and $j\in[1,n]$) is a number describing how bond $i$ is related to bond $j$. This could be the $\beta$ from regressing the change-on-day of each bond $j$ against each bond $i$ separately. Then we can get our $(5y,10y,30y)$ risk vector by doing $$S_B=JS_A.$$ This will give our clear macro risk broken down into the 5y, 10y, and 30y buckets.

**Other methods**

My question is what other methods exist in the literature to transform the risk of a full bond portfolio into more macro components to get a simplified view of the risk.

I'm generally looking for more advanced methods that may not typically be implemented in practice due to impracticalities. Happy to receive both explanations of the methods as well as references to literature.

Comment: >After applying PCA with 3 components. Isn't this number rather arbitrary? I could see how higher order PCs can be difficult to interpret, but still why not choose more or less components to explain a certain threshold in variance.

Comment: I understand that with *risk representation* you mean something like $DV01=PV(y+1bp)-PV(y)$ or $CS01=PV(r,cs+1bp)-PV(r,cs)$ or something alike?

Comment: @SergeiRodionov The number is rather arbitrary (except for PC1 since this quite explicitly explains the outright movements) - hence why I'm in search for other methods...

Comment: @Kermittfrog By risk representation I mean a vector of $n$ numbers where each number is the dv01 risk in the bond, for example, risk vevtor $S=(r_1,r_2,r_3,r_4,r_5,r_6,r_7,r_8,r_9,r_{10},r_{12},r_{14},r_{15},r_{16},r_{18},r_{20},r_{22},r_{25},r_{27},r_{28},r_{30},r_{35},r_{37},r_{39},r_{40})$ where $r_i$ is the dv01 position in bond $i$. I'm looking for transformation methods to reduce this down to broad macro exposure such as $(r_5,r_{10},r_{30})$ which is much more useful for managing overall risk

Comment: The transformations that I commonly see in banks' risk teams is to calculate bonds' zero rate sensitivities w.r.t. various 'pillar' nodes on a 'base/pure' interest rate curve (let's say swap for simplicity) and another 'stacked' curve of credit spreads. The idea here is to more or less manage the bond portfolio's risk using liquid reference instruments for interest rate risk (swaps) and for the credit spread risk - As you have stated in your method 2, more or less. This way, risk/pnl is linearly attributed to reference instruments' performance.

Comment: @Kermittfrog Yes thanks I'm aware of this (what you're saying in that comment is pretty much what I put in my last comment); I'm in search of methods other than the one stated in the question.

Comment: No, it is not the same I think. DV01 is the change in PV wrt the bond‘s yield, no? the measures I commonly observe are built against (zero)curves that are built using multiple reference instruments. Nevertheless, these methods are still within the class of what you have stated, yes.

Comment: @SergeiRodionov regarding the number of PCs, it depends on what you do with them. The first 3 have clear geometric interpretation (up-down, slope, curvature), used to explain > 99% of the curves' variance when Litterman et al wrote about it in 1991 (explain <99% for many curves these days), so the sensitivities to the first 3 PCs are a nice feature for an IR risk report. The next few PCs don't have such clear geometric interpretation (double humps..) and sensitivity to them on a risk report isn't very insightful. However if instead of sensitivities report you're  (cont)

Comment: trying to generate lots of Monte-Carlo scenarios of the PCs, and then look at the tail <1% (e.g. for VaR or ES), then 3 PCs are clearly not enough, and people use at least 6-8 PCs that historically explained more of the curves' variance than 3 did. (personally, I'm not super comfortable with this anyway, but it's better than simulating with just 3 PCs).

Comment: could you please elaborate on 'risk representation' in your question? are you looking for a many-to-three mapping such that a risk measure (any particular one?) of the many-piece portfolio is the same as of the three-piece one?

Comment: @IgorPozdeev I'm looking for a many-to-$X$ mapping/transformation where $X$ are the liquid instruments. For example, across the bond curve, the liquid points may be considered the 5y, 10y, and 30y points, so knowing how your entire portfolio behaves relative to those three points is useful. So in this case the mapping is $(r_1,r_2,...,r_n)\rightarrow (r_5,r_{10},r_{30})$, where $n$ is the number of bonds in the portfolio. If $(r_5,r_{10},r_{30})=(-50k,100k,-50k)$, then your portfolio trades like a 5s10s30s steepener in 100k dv01.

Comment: @IgorPozdeev The Jacobian method above does this pretty well, which I use to manage risk at work, but I'm curious about other methods in the literature or that people on here have developed

Comment: Any updates how PCA can transform the risk of illiquid tenors into liquid/macro ones? I got the first 3 PCs but not too sure what to do afterwards

Comment: I have stated a very similar question here https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/77280/dimension-reduction-of-par-risk-strips?noredirect=1#comment113895_77280 but I also don’t saw a more superior method than the Jacobian/PCA approach though I‘m pretty sure it exists (see my last comment in the link w.r.t. „weighted dv01“)